# Sending XML data through a WebRequest in VB

Tags: xml, vb.net, http

I was asked to write some code to interface with the Wi-Flight Api in visual basic. I already have code to login and interface with the API.

I am writing some sample code to submit a reservation. To do this, I have created an XML file using an XmlTextWriter. I now need to submit the data to Wi-Flight servers by sending the data in a PUT request like [this](https://www.wi-flight.net/docs/api.html#resvcreate).

I have looked around to try and find a way to send the data through a WebRequest and the best I go is [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/623331.aspx/1) but I don't seem to understand how to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
    wc.UploadFile("SERVER_URI", "PUT", "PATH_TO_XML_FILE")
End Using
```

If you haven't the XML file saved, you could put a String content in a similar way:

```
Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient()
    wc.UploadString("SERVER_URI", "PUT", XML_Content)
End Using
```